# Calling a Static Custom Module Block in a CMS page

Tags: magento

In my CMS contact-us page, I have the following code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Which pulls in Magento's standard Contact Form. I have installed a new module from Fontis called recaptcha to prevent spam. This is located my_theme/default/template/fontis/recaptcha/contacts.phtml.

Is anyone able to tell me how I correctly modify the above code to use the new form please? 
I have tried changing: `template="contacts/form.phtml"` to `template="fontis/recaptcha/contacts.phtml"` but this doesnt seem to work, not sure if I need to alter the block type to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modification is generally correct to change a template path. Specifically, what do you mean when you say it "doesn't" work? Without more information on what you're seeing, it's difficult to help you debug this issue.

Thanks!
Joe

---

Sounds like a caching issue to me, or that you're changing the template on the wrong declaration. First, turn off all caching on your site and try again. If that doesn't work, turn on template path hints and make sure that you are editing what you think you are.

Comment: Thanks Joe, your right I should have been clearer on how it doesnt work. Basically It continues to use the Magento Contact form rather than the one in the fontis directory structure. I also tried altering type="core/template" to various things but this got rid of the contact form completely presumably because it was completely wrong. Thanks